# How big are transactions when making a PocketChange transaction with Monerujo wallet?

Tags: monerujo, pocketchange

Monerujo has a feature called PocketChange which splits change into multiple outputs. This increases the transaction size, but by how much? And do other wallets have this type of feature?

Answer (score 0):

A typical 1 input 2 output transaction is ~1.49 kB ([ref](https://xmrchain.net/tx/a68951abaa9fa2bedbb26be1db0fa5e42cbabd939d41692ff93ce0851de2e05f)).

A 1 input 16 output transaction is ~3.2 kB ([ref](https://xmrchain.net/tx/488245c7733181400a56ede8be3159d31b6e5d26673b9288df0f29a8ca902df4), assume this is a PocketChange transaction).

Therefore in this example, a PocketChange transaction is just over twice the size of a normal transaction.

It's worth pointing out that it's the *input* count that is the more defining aspect to overall transaction size, as *each* input requires a ring signature, but PocketChange is about creating more *outputs*, not inputs.

Comment: wouldn't one be able to reveal if a user just made a pocket change transaction? how does ring signature hide things if a transaction contains 1 input and 16 outputs.

Comment: "how does ring signature hide things if a transaction contains 1 input and 16 outputs" The same as any 1 in, 16 out tx. And remember, that 1 input is in a ring of 16 other possible inputs; each input has its *own* ring.